# error CS0117: 'Level' does not contain a definition for 'Instance'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am New to *C#*. Want to develop game. Unity has changed some of the syntax like Application. Not able to resolve the error.Checked everything spelling. How Instance work here.

Tried searching in Unity documentation and in google. Its from the book i am learning.Available in google. If we type the code it gives the book.

**Blockquote**

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 using RunAndJump;
 using UnityEditor;

    [ExecuteInEditMode] public class SnapToGridTest : MonoBehaviour {
 // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
     {
         Vector3 gridCoord = 
              Level.Instance.WorldToGridCoordinates(transform.position);
         transform.position = 
              Level.Instance.GridToWorldCoordinates((int)gridCoord.x,
         (int)gridCoord.y);
     }

     private void OnDrawGizmos()
     {
         Color oldColor = Gizmos.color;
         Gizmos.color = (Level.Instance.IsInsideGridBounds(transform.position)) 
                         ? Color.green
                                     : Color.red;
         Gizmos.DrawCube (transform.position, Vector3.one * Level.GridSize);
         Gizmos.color = oldColor;
     } }
```

**Blockquote**

> error CS0117: 'Level' does not contain a definition for 'Instance'

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the code for `Level` but as the error states ... there is no `Instance` defined .. maybe you or the book are missing something ;)

Comment: I haven't got deep understanding of your library, but if you work with Visual Studio or some IDE, if you just write Level then write a `.`, the IDE should suggest you something where you could find the method you are looking for.

Comment: Can you show your script for `Level`?

Comment: https://resources.oreilly.com/examples/9781785281853/blob/7792216dc661b69445d665643ac726c8ae71687d/B04640_Extending%20Unity%20with%20Editor%20Scripting_Code/Chapter%202/Scripts/Level/Level.cs

Comment: @madhans the link you provided is a `partial class` so .. where is the rest of it? In the part you linked at least there is no `Instance` nowhere

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying treat Level as a [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), but the singleton for Level isn't implemented yet.

You can implement a Singleton as so:

```
private static Level instance;

public static Level Instance 
{
    get 
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = FindObjectOfType<Level>();
        }

        return instance
     }
}
```

Of course, it won't work if there isn't a `GameObject` with a `Level` component attached to it on the current scene.

Also, it seems like the tutorial book that you are currently following along had made `Level` as a partial class.
 The guide might have made another script for partial `Level` class that contains the Singleton.
You might have just missed it, or the guide had not gone to that part yet.

Comment: Just have to add, because FindObjectOfType is pretty slow method, you should use a method instead of property.
Because property usually imply that their implementation is fast and reliable.